# How to update one record from another record with same fields using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the exact same table in 2 different db's. A user updates one table but I need to programmatically update the other table in the 2nd db (Head office/branch - thus 2 different db's)

I make reference to the 2nd table and select the record I want updated.

Question is, Can I update the entire record at one go instead of assigning each value to be updated?

PS. I need the ID to be unchanged. So deleting and adding in a new record is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which db server are you using  now ?

Comment: Is this something you can do in the database? Using stored procedures or database-sync?

Comment: @NaveenSoni sql server

Comment: Can use Replication for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-2017